# Vim line numbers, absolute within visual mode and relative within insert

Tags: vim

I have line numbers set within my .vimrc.

I'm wanting to switch to relativenumbers when in insert mode, and switch back to regular numbers in visual mode.

I've tried:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * :set number
autocmd InsertLeave * :set relativenumber
```

But this isn't working. I'm using Vim7.4.52 in terminal, Ubuntu.

If possible I want to do this automatically, so I haven't got to fiddle with manually entering a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`number` and `relativenumber` setting are not exclusive anymore, so rather use something like this:

`autocmd InsertEnter * :set nonumber relativenumber
autocmd InsertLeave * :set number norelativenumber`

Or use one of the many plugins, that do that (sorry, I don't remember which ones do that).